# Mutually exclusive gh-pages branch

Tags: github-pages

I am using gh-pages on GitHub.

I do NOT want the content from master to be included on the gh-pages branch.

I do not have the ability to use --orphan (don't have sudo permission and git isn't up to date.)

if i use `git checkout -b gh-pages` all of the content from master is included in the gh-pages branch.  I do not want them to share any content.

How do I generate a clean branch without removing content from master or using the `--orphan` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index
```

Then now `git add`, `git commit` etc.

Comment: When I do this, no new branch is created on my local and all of the content from the master branch is still there.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you need to prepare the commit as you see fit (for example remove the unwanted files, then make your commit).